# Unexpected behavior using Threads.@threads?

Tags: multithreading, julia

In the code below, the inner loop creates a vector of all 1's, and then sets each value of the vector to 0. The sum of this vector is expected to then be 0. But, if I use `Threads.@threads` on the inner loop, sometimes it isn't. Am I violating a rule about multithreading with this code? It seems that the inner loop does not always "finish". I have JULIA_NUM_THREADS set to 4.

```
N = 1000
M = 1000
for i in 1:N
    test = trues(M)
    Threads.@threads for j in 1:M
        test[j] = 0
    end
    s = sum(test)
    if s > 0
        println("sum(M) was ", s, "!")
    end
end
println("done!")
```

Sample output:

[image]

There do not seem to be any problems with using `Threads.@threads` on the outer loop. How can I predict where it is OK to use `Threads.@threads` and where it is not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because [`trues`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.trues) creates a [`BitArray`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.BitArray), where boolean values are efficiently packed as individual bits in 64-bit chunks. As a result, accesses to adjacent indices can be racy.

This is discussed in the following [issue](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/33750), and should be documented as soon as this [PR](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/33754) is merged.

The problem disappears if you use an other array type, such as `Vector{Bool}`:

```
N = 1000
M = 1000
for i in 1:N
    test = ones(Bool, M) # creates a Vector{Bool}
    Threads.@threads for j in 1:M
        test[j] = 0
    end
    s = sum(test)
    if s > 0
        println("sum(M) was ", s, "!")
    end
end
println("done!")
```

Comment: Yikes! I am actually working with large BitArrays on purpose, to save memory (though I may be OK switching to Array{Bool}s). Am I right in thinking that it's OK to use @threads on the outer loop in the example, since each thread would get an entire BitArray?

Comment: Yes, if `@threads` is used on the outer loop in this example, a different `test` array should be created at each iteration, so that there should be no concurrent accesses.

Comment: Thanks! appreciate the quick help.

Comment: So the problem is actually that as each address point to a byte and not a bit, there are groups of 8 elements of the BitArray that share the same address?

Comment: It's not quite that, it's more that modifying the `ith` element of a BitArray can cause updates to some neighboring elements to be overwritten if they happen at the same time

Comment: From the linked issue: "If it's just overwriting without resizing (so be careful with sparse array), as long as different elements are at distinct memory location it'll be fine. BitArray violates this so it's unsafe." But true and false have the same size, so the problem is the addressing, no?

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the race condition you should also be aware that iterating over and modifying elements in a `BitArray` is much slower than doing the same with an `Array{Bool}`. `BitArray`s are memory-efficient, and can be extremely fast for chunked operations, but are not good for individual element access:

```
using BenchmarkTools, Random

function itertest!(a)
    for i in eachindex(a)
        @inbounds a[i] = !a[i]
    end
end

julia> @btime itertest!(a) setup=(a=rand(Bool, 1000));
  70.050 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> @btime itertest!(a) setup=(a=bitrand(1000));
  2.211 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

On the other hand, for chunked operations, performance is stellar:

```
function dottest!(a)
    a .= .!a
end

julia> @btime dottest!(a) setup=(a=rand(Bool, 1000));
  71.795 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> @btime dottest!(a) setup=(a=bitrand(1000));
  6.904 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```